# How to print the hidden column to csv file in R

Tags: r

I am new to R, using others script. I want to save a data frame to csv file. There should have three columns.

```
print(resultData)
                Name A        Name B
1995-06-07      9.866522e+00  2.717378e+00
1995-06-08      9.867985e+00  2.715913e+00
1995-06-09      9.859632e+00  2.707559e+00
```

When I do `write.csv()`

```
write.csv(resultData, file="log.txt", row.names=TRUE)

"","Name A","Name B"
"10902",9.86301036126783,2.68187056180675
"10903",9.86184368463656,2.68303587888967
"10904",9.85092788914247,2.69383380526988
```

I want to keep the first column in date format rather than as a number, but how to do it?

Comment: Perhaps you need to pass `rowname` to a column. `df$MyRowNames <- rownames(df)`

Comment: Maybe `row.names(resultData) <- as.character(row.names(resultData))`.

Comment: Your problem comes from the date format. The solution of Rui Barradas is the best. You don't want to use the save function of R which saves your result in R format ?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, @RuiBarradas, I would like to ask where should I put the command? Sorry for my silly question. I have tried to use it but it makes no difference. I have tried to call `as.character(row.names(resultData))`, and it returned NULL.

Comment: Those Dates are your rownames right? Strangely when I do `write.csv(resultData, file="log.txt")` I can see them in `Date` format and not as numbers.

Comment: I found that I can do `as.character(index(resultData))` and see those Date again. I am sorry, they may not be the rownames. So how can I print those Date with my two columns to csv file?

Comment: Can you post `dput(head(resultData))` ?

Comment: structure(c(0.00167228338845363, 0.00125404832816473, -0.00252429818470144,
-0.00589414448984377, -0.000864743756013115, 0.00413940559567309,
0.00167228338845363, 0.00125404832816473, -0.00252429818470144,
-0.00589414448984377, -0.000864743756013115, 0.00413940559567309
), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(-567820800,
-567561600, -567475200, -567388800, -567302400, -567216000), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(6L,
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Name A", "Name B"
`)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `zoo` object

```
class(resultData)
#[1] "xts" "zoo"
```

which do not have rownames

```
rownames(resultData)
#NULL
```

Convert them to data.frame and then use `write.csv`

```
write.csv(data.frame(resultData), file="log.txt")
```

or if you want `date` as separate column

```
write.csv(cbind(date = index(resultData), data.frame(resultData)), 
          file="log.txt", row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your object is an xts object so use `write.zoo` to write it, not `write.csv`.  If `x` is your object then:

```
library(xts)

# write.zoo(x, "myfile.dat")
write.zoo(x, stdout())
## "Index" "Name A" "Name B"
## "1952-01-04" 0.00167228338845363 0.00167228338845363
## "1952-01-07" 0.00125404832816473 0.00125404832816473
## "1952-01-08" -0.00252429818470144 -0.00252429818470144
## "1952-01-09" -0.00589414448984377 -0.00589414448984377
## "1952-01-10" -0.000864743756013115 -0.000864743756013115
## "1952-01-11" 0.00413940559567309 0.00413940559567309
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your dates are being stored as the number of days since `August 30th 1965`. 
Because CSV files are just commas and text, the 'correct' formatting will depend on what you want to do with your CSV file.

If you want an easy to understand date string, try base R function `as.Date`:

```
> as.Date(10902, origin = "1965-08-30")
[1] "1995-07-06"
```

Reformatting your first column could be done like this:

```
resultData[,1] = as.Date(resultData[,1], origin = "1965-08-03")
colnames(resultData)[1] = "Date" #Adding column name to make beautiful
write.csv(resultData, file="log.txt", row.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get error message `Error in as.Date.default(x, ...) do not know how to convert 'x' to class "Date"`

Comment: You're probably passing a string instead of an int. Try using `as.numeric`:

`resultData[,1] = as.Date(as.numeric(resultData[,1]), origin = "1965-08-03")`